# Синонимизировать [word] и [msword]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки [word](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) и [msword](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msword) значат одно и то же, по крайней мере именно так и используются. Было бы идеально создать метку [ms-word](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) (как на enSO) и синонимизировать их туда.

Comment: [Как минимум один вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753873) не про MS Word, так что нужно будет по ним пробежаться

Comment: @andreymal Удалил все три случая некорректного использования метки, включая упомянутый.

Comment: Так может то были как раз **корректные** случаи, а остались некорректные :)

Comment: @alexolut 3 корректных и 132 некорректных?:) А если серьёзно, то метка [tag:word] там вообще ничего конкретного не добавляла к посту и случаи были друг с другом никак не связаны. Это было [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546935/220571), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756013/220571), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/753873/220571).

Comment: А вы не забыли о том что [tag:word] с английского переводится как `слово`?

Comment: @LLENN Конечно, нет. Но у нас его так не употребляют и такое употребление будет, как мне кажется, бессмысленным. По этой метке даже больше вопросов, чем [tag:msword] и все именно такие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метка [ms-word](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) создана, к ней синонимизированы [word](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) и [msword](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msword)